# How to use Webpack ProvidePlugin to load Backbone-relational right?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webpack, backbone-relational

I have defined webpack ProvidePlugin to load Backbone-relational library as follows.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $ : "jquery",
        Backbone : "backbone",
        _ : "underscore",
        "Backbone.Relational": "backbone-relational",
    })
```

However Backbone-relational also exports:

- Backbone.RelationalModel
- Backbone.HasOne
- Backbone.HasMany
- etc...

My problem is that I can not have them all exported. What is the right way to do this with webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use relational shim as described [here](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/570#issuecomment-222680425)